# ASP. MVC JsonResult

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Hello I am trying to pass the parameter id to the a JsonResult. Currently the code below works if I hard code my id and when I do not pass a parameter through.

The code below is for the Events Calendar View

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: "prev,next,today",
                center:'title',
                right:''
                //   right: 'month'
            },
            defaultView: 'month',
            editable:false,
            allDaySlot: false,
            selectable: true,
            slotMinutes: 15,
            firstDay:1,
            events: 'GetEvents/'
        });
    });
</script>

<div id='calendar' style="width:90%">

</div>
```

JsonResult where the id is currently hard coded I would like to pass this value through when I click the button to load the page e.g. /EventsCalendar/2

```
public JsonResult GetEvents(string start , string end) 
{
    int id = 1; 
    var events = CustomEvents(start , end, id );            
    return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);         
}
```

Item 2 is the name of the button and Item 1 is the name

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Item2, "ShowEvents", new { controller = "Leaves", id = item.Item1 }, new { @Class = "btn btn-primary" })

public ActionResult EventsCalendar()
{   
    return View(); 
}
```

Comment: Your link calls the `ShowEvents()` method, not `EventsCalendar()` - and the method needs a parameter `int id` to bind the value.

Comment: Hello I have added  GetEvents(string start, string end, int? calcgroup)  and change the view to 
events: 'GetCustomCalander?calcgroup'+ @calcgroup sadly it still doesn't work

Comment: fullCalendar supports a custom events function - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ - if you use that you can pass your ID as an extra parameter to the GetEvents action. When the view first loads you just need to store ID somewhere in JS variable that can then be passed back to GetEvents as a parameter.